# Photoswipe Mobile / Touch Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, photoswipe

I am using this [Animated Responsive Image Grid with Photoswipe](http://codepen.io/mrnathan8/pen/RPoOaG) on codepen. The demo works perfectly on desktop but on mobile I get the following console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined index.js:285

```
gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {
  if (useLargeImages) {
    item.src = item.o.src;
    item.w = item.o.w;
    item.h = item.o.h;
  } else {
    item.src = item.m.src;
    item.w = item.m.w;
    item.h = item.m.h;
  }
});
```

This demo uses [Animated Responsive Image Grid](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/) & [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following to get rid of the console error

```
else {
      item.src = item.m.src;
      item.w = item.m.w;
      item.h = item.m.h;
    }
```